# How do I display all columns from a table while using SELECT DISTINCT & MAX(ID) to remove duplicates?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, distinct, max

I have a table that, in some instances, has more than one entry for the same employee.

I only want the employee record with the highest ID.

Example of table structure & data

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    Initials    AreaID  SupervisorID    Forms   JobClass    JobTitle
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
805/    Trey/   W/  TW/ 93/ 404/    99/NA/  Temporary/ R1_Temp
752/    Trey/   W/  TW/ 93/ 404/    99/NA/  Temporary/ R1_Temp 
399/    Ron/    V/  RV/ 144/    NULL/   99/NULL/    NULL/   NULL
374/    Ron/    V/  RV/ 94/ NULL/   99/NULL/    NULL/   NULL
379/    Ron/    V/  NULL/   0/  NULL/   99/NULL/    NULL/   NULL
378/    Dax/    T/  NULL/   0/  NULL/   40/NULL/    NULL/   NULL
373/    Dax/    T/  DT/ 94/ NULL/   40/NULL/    NULL/   NULL
398/    Dax/    T/  DT/ 94/ 276/    99/NULL/    NULL/   NULL
```

As you can see, there are three entries for Ron V.

There are currently ~1000 entries (including duplicates).  The query below returns ~700 (excluding duplicates), which is correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName, MAX(ID) as ID
FROM Employees GROUP BY LastName 
order by LastName DESC
```

This only returns the ID and LastName.  We need to return all the values in the table above.  How do I do it in a single query?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and the [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function to select the row with the largest ID for each distinct `FirstName`/`LastName` pair.

This is the `SELECT` statement:

```
;with DistinctByName as (
  select 
    *,
    row_number() 
      over (
        partition by FirstName, LastName
        order by ID desc
      ) as RowNumber
  from Employees
)
select 
  [ID], 
  [FirstName], [LastName], [Initials], 
  [AreaID], [SupervisorID], [Forms], 
  [JobClass], [JobTitle]
from DistinctByName
where RowNumber = 1
```

You can try this code online: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a791e/2

A brief explanation about why this works:
The `row_number()` function above returns the index of the current row among all rows that have the same `FirstName` and `LastName` (the `partition by` clause), ordered in descending order of `ID`.

The `row_number()` function cannot appear in the `WHERE` clause, so we have to wrap the select in a CTE in order to be able to filter by this value.

The outer `SELECT` statement has the condition `where RowNumber = 1`, meaning that for eny distinct FirstName/LastName pair we only take the record with the highest `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rejoin to the table. Something like the following should probably work.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT LastName, MAX(ID) as ID FROM Employees
) distinctRows
inner join Employees e on e.ID = distinctRows.ID
```

Comment: Column 'Employees.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: the inner select statement should contain a `GROUP BY` clause instead of `DISTINCT`, because it also contains aggregate values (`max(ID)`). Here's a fixed version: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a791e/5

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot the group by part. However rejoining will work once you add the group by to the inner select